# Inheritance of window properties set in Activity

Tags: android

I'm configuring my Activity to run in fullscreen mode:

```
Window window  = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
window.setAttributes(params);
```

However, as soon as I open a dialog on it, this constraint goes away, given the dialog has its own dialog object.

Is there any way to enforce or "inherit" configuration of the window object from the activity to any contained object in the UI?

Answer (score -1):

For fullscreen mode, place this on your onCreate after the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState):

> this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);